# Validation not working for ImageButton click

Tags: c#, validation

I have an image button for login in my system. so as the most common thing i m having two text boxes `txt_username` and `txt_password`.
i have put required field validator for both the text boxes. and set the validation group "a" and respective control to validate for both of them. the source code for my ImageButton is as follows:-

```
<td align="right" class="simple_text">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="left">
     <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="true"
          ImageUrl="~/images/signin_button.gif" onclick="ImageButton1_Click" 
          ValidationGroup="a" />
 </td>
```

now I am fed up as when I  run my application and click the ImageButton it doesn't respond to the validation at all and redirects to the next page. Can anyone say why is it so? this is the first time wherein the validators are not working.

this is source code:-

```
<td align="left"><table width="480" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="178" align="right" class="simple_text">User Name :&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="302" align="left">

                &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txt_username" runat="server" 
                    CssClass="text_box_username" Width="180px" AutoPostBack="True" 
                    ontextchanged="txt_username_TextChanged" ValidationGroup="a" 
                    CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="txt_username" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" 
                    ValidationGroup="a">**</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
          </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" class="simple_text">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" class="simple_text">Password :&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_password" runat="server" CssClass="text_box_password" 
                    TextMode="Password" Width="180px" ValidationGroup="a" 
                    CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="txt_password" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" 
                    ValidationGroup="a">**</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" class="simple_text">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" class="simple_text">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="true"
                    ImageUrl="~/images/signin_button.gif" onclick="ImageButton1_Click" 
                    ValidationGroup="a" />
              </td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
```

Comment: What do the validators look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi just paste this code will work surely for you

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <td align="left"><table width="480" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="178" align="right" class="simple_text">User Name :&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="302" align="left">

                &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txt_username" runat="server" 
                     Width="180px" AutoPostBack="True" 
                     ValidationGroup="a" 
                    CausesValidation="True" ontextchanged="txt_username_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="txt_username" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" 
                    ValidationGroup="a">**</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
          </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" class="simple_text">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" class="simple_text">Password :&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_password" runat="server" 
                    TextMode="Password" Width="180px" ValidationGroup="a" 
                    CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="txt_password" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" 
                    ValidationGroup="a">**</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" class="simple_text">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" class="simple_text">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="true"
                    ImageUrl="~/images/signin_button.gif" onclick="ImageButton1_Click" 
                    ValidationGroup="a" />
              </td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you provided the validationGroup property properly.

[Specifying Validation Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx)

Comment: ya i have specified them properly. Thats the thing . When all properties are proper whats the problem?

Comment: when i edit my question and paste my source code it is not visible sometimes. where should i place my source code? sorry bt i m new to this stack overflow.

Comment: After pasting the source code, select the source code and click on the {} (curlybraces) button on the editor. It will help you to paste the source code

Comment: The code provided works fine for me. Why you provided autopostback for username textbox?

Comment: i am comparing the valid username from database in the txt_uername.textchanged event. so its set to true.

Comment: Then I don't think it will work as you expecting, because the Validation control fire, when ever there is a postback.

Comment: then should i put my txt_changed event code in button_click? and set false the autopostback property?

Comment: this same code works for my another form in another website. bt dosent work for this website after applyinf css.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" CausesValidation="true" ImageUrl="..." />
```

CausesValidation="true" might force the validation to run.